# How to divide a project into classes

Tags: java, c#, c++

- On what basis should I divide the project into classes?
- Up to how many classes can I subdivide the project? How should I know when to stop?
- Is it good practice to keep the whole project in a single class?

Comment: If, I don't know, Google Chrome was in one class, I'd cry.

Comment: You need to learn basics of OOP and Design

Comment: @PradeepSimha I think that is exactly what the OP is looking for. A nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Programming is also a matter of instinct. There are many rules of thumb, like "split functions longer than XXX lines", and "let a class have exactly one responsibility, not more". To add to Pradeep, you may also want to look into software architecture, code smells, refactoring. There is a long way to go.

Comment: Thank you phresnel. And yes dtryon, i was indeed looking for a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On what basis should I divide the project into classes?

Break up your code into logical components. You want to make your code as simple and clear as possible.  Imagine someone who doesn't know/remember what your project does and doesn't want to read every line of code in your project to be able to maintain it. (This could be you in six months time)  How would you make it as easy as possible for some one to find the part of the system which is needs their attention.

> Up to how many classes can I subdivide the project? How should I know when to stop?

I would make each class about one to tens screenfulls (very approximately)

Anything over 10,000 clases is likely to be a very large project.

> Is it good practice to keep the whole project in a single class?

If the project is very, very simple, yes. Many of the short examples on this forum are just one method or one class.

If it is reasonably simple, a couple of classes may be all that is needed. For a major projects, hundreds or even thousands is likely to be a reasonable number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't have found a better answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK, The question was closed because it's not possible to give a difinitive answer.  IMHO The main thing is; write simple, clear, easy to maintain code and your co-workers will thank you for it. ;)  These are usually far more important than performance esp as simple, clear code often performs well.

Comment: Well, every question I post here has been closed for one reason or the other :(  I was looking for an answer like yours so I would get an idea as to how the subclassing is done. IMHO, your answer was all I was looking for :)

Comment: @holygirl if there is a better forum for subjective questions, I don't know what it is.

Comment: That's alright. Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: Btw, I'm banned from posting anymore questions on this site so I went to <http://qt-project.org> and I must say they are one of the sweetest and most helpful people I've ever come across. They don't insult you or pass cheeky comments at your questions however stupid my questions maybe.

Comment: IMHO There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers. ;)

Comment: Ha ha! You are smart. And sweet too. YOU should be on <http://qt-project.org>. They'll worship you :)

Comment: @holygirl You are too kind.  I don't use `qt` but if I did I would.  You might like my blog http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: I'm checking it out. It looks fun with puzzles and memes and SO much information. I haven't really worked on core java except a couple of small projects in college. But I'll definitely pass it on to my friends who work on Java and I'll bookmark so I can do a little learning myself :)

Comment: Oh and I absolutely adore how you've provided so many UI options like Flipcard, Snapshot etc.

Comment: The blog has had almost 2 million page views.

Comment: WOW! Do you manage the blog all by yourself? It's amazing.

Comment: @holygirl Thanks, you can also follow my twitter if you like, fans welcome ;)

Comment: Ha ha! Way to promote yourself. I sure will :)